# Overloading varargs arrays, choosing method

Tags: java, overloading

I have a two overloaded methods: `foo` and `bar`

```
//Object[]... vs Integer[]...
public static String foo(Object[]... args)  { return "Object[] args"; }
public static String foo(Integer[]... args) { return "Integer[] args";}

//Object... vs Integer[]...
public static String bar(Object... args) {return "Object args";}
public static String bar(Integer[]... args) {return "Integer[] args";}
```

Now when I use them like:

```
Integer[] i = { 5 };
System.out.println(foo(i));//Object[]... vs Integer[]...
System.out.println(bar(i));//Object... vs Integer[]...
```

I am getting

```
Integer[] args
Object args
```

Here is the question: why do we have 2 different outputs?
`Integer[]` can be implicitly cast to both `Object`, and `Object[]`.

Comment: For those who want to play Sherlock [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

Comment: you should at least mention the compiler warning.

Comment: @Colonel, yes you can and yes you can.  You'll get a runtime exception when you try it.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) and Java 8 and not have any warning for:                     Integer[] arrayInts = new Integer[5];
 Object[] arrayObject = arrayInts;

Comment: It's my screen [link](http://screencast.com/t/Ex3rbgK2NMd)

Comment: @NathanHughes wasn't talking about warning with casting Integer[] to Object[], but warning when you call your method in second case (Object... vs Integer[]...).

Comment: @Pshemo: oops, i meant my comment for the OP. when i try this (with java 8) i get "warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument
type for last parameter"

Comment: @NathanHughes My comment was meant for OP, I simply forgot to remove `@`. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically compiler deciding to call the most specific method among all.

When you call

```
System.out.println(foo(i));//Object[]... vs Integer[]...
```

it will call the `foo(Integer[]... args)`

Because at run time the JVM delegates the call to the method with `Integer[][]` argument and **not method with `Object[][]`  param** as specified by varags. As it will be more specific to call method with Integer[][] rather than Object[][].

---

In the later statement, when you call

`System.out.println(bar(i));//Object... vs Integer[]...`

it will go to the `bar(Object... args)`

Again by using varags, the type of param will be Object[] and not Object[][]. Again the compiler will call the most specific method which will be the one having `Object... args`.

If you change the method signature by removing varags as per following:

```
   //Object... vs Integer[]...
    public static String bar(Object args) {

        return "Object args";
    }

    public static String bar(Integer[] args) {
        return "Integer[] args";
    }
```

then you will notice that it will call the `bar(Integer[] args)` as it is more specific to the method call.

So to be more precise as per [JLS Subtyping among Array Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3),

- If S and T are both reference types, then S[] > T[] iff S > T.
- Object > Object[]

This means that a call of Integer[] will be made to method having Integer[][] and not Object[][].
Where as a call of Integer[] will be made to Object[] rather than Integer[][].

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) for choosing the most specific method.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the type of args is actually Integer[][], i.e., your array was boxed up into another array by varargs.  The compiler chooses the Integer[] version because it is the most specific type.

In the second case, args == i and is an Integer[].  In this case, the compiler had to choose between wrapping it up in a new array to call the Integer[]... version or just casting your Integer[] to an Object[].  It chose the second one because that's the rule.

The moral of the story is:  don't overload varargs methods -- it's confusing.

Comment: Can you find the bit of the spec that says `that's the rule`?

Comment: I could...  but the OP has already proven it with his compiler :)

Comment: If you can find it, I'll upvote. I'm having trouble deciphering it.

Comment: When you explicitly provide an array, then the arguments match the parameter types without "variable arity invocation", and the method will be found in phase 1 or phase 2 of the search for compatible methods.  Otherwise, a phase 3 search will be performed to find methods that can be invoked by doing the varargs wrapping thing.  It's kind of all spread out in section 15.12